# How the EXPORTING method parameters passed by value?

Tags: abap, method-call, call-by-value

I'm wondering about the definition of a call-by-value EXPORTING argument of an ABAP method call.

The SAP Help Portal states that EXPORTING parameters can be defined call-by-value (and call by reference).  It does not give a precise definition of how this parameter type is handled. Instead, it states

> For precise details of the relevant ABAP statements, refer to the
>   corresponding keyword documentation in the ABAP Editor.

Now, the ABAP Keyword Documentation of the SAP editor does not mention pass-by-value for EXPORTING.  (It does mention pass-by-value for IMPORTING and CHANGING).

I can guess the meaning of pass-by-value EXPORTING.  But I want to read the definition.  From FORM/PERFORM, I know that details can be subtle.  Could you point me to an official description of this case?

Comment: Well, the ABAP reference states "When called, either a reference to an actual parameter is passed, [...] depending on the passing type. Maybe that could count as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure in what way the details can be subtle even when using `FORM`s - but anyway, it's in [the documentation:](https://help.sap.com/doc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/ABENFUNCTION_PARAMETERS.htm)

> There are two ways in which parameters can be passed: pass by
>   reference and pass by value. Pass by value is selected in the Function
>   Builder by selecting pass by value, and in the above syntax, differs
>   from pass by reference by the specification of `VALUE( )`.
>
> - In pass by reference, the formal parameter points directly to the    actual parameter, so that changes to the formal parameters have an
>     immediate effect on the actual parameter.
> - In pass by value, when the function module is called, the formal    parameter is created as a copy of the actual parameter (in `IMPORTING`
>     and `CHANGING` parameters), or initial (in `EXPORTING` parameters) in
>     the    stack. In `CHANGING` and `EXPORTING` parameters, the formal
>     parameter is    copied to the actual parameter when returning from the
>     function    module.